# How to install package with local path by Yarn? It couldn't find package

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

In my `package.json` I'm pointing local package `my-custom-i18n` by its relative path:

#### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
 "core-js": "^2.4.1",
 "my-custom-i18n": "./../MyProject.Shared/myproject-i18n",
 "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
 ...
}
```

`npm install` installs packages correctly, but `yarn` has problem with it and simply cannot find this package:

#### yarn output

```
$ yarn
yarn install v0.15.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "myproject-i18n" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit http://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I see that it looks it on the `npm` registry, where this package doesn't live.

#### Question

Is there any change to use yarn with local packages?
By local packages I mean packages pointed by relative path as `my-custom-i18n`.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

### For yarn version < 2.x

Yarn requires prefix `file:` for local packages.

For relative path:

```
yarn add file:./../your-project
```

For absolute path

```
yarn add file:/dev/your-project
```

For your example, dependency in `package.json` would be declared as follows:

```
 "my-custom-i18n": "file:./../MyProject.Shared/myproject-i18n",
```

This works both for Yarn and NPM as well.

It is incompatibility with NPM client, Yarn team is aware and declared to support this behavior - [reference on GitHub issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/605).

**Update:**

Since *v0.21.0* release, `file:` prefix is not needed.
See [pull-request with fix](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/2617) and [changelog](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/tag/v0.21.0).

Comment: thanks, works like a charm. But if it's not compatible with npm client for now - I'll just leave `npm` as it is :)
PS my idea was to use `yarn` only locally without converting whole team and project. So .. I'll have to wait till support for this :)

Comment: make sure you clear your cache. as yarn always try cached version first

Comment: +1 for the update! Removing `file:` prefix solved a problem we had where `yarn install` on windows would add `./` prefix to relative file paths, but `yarn install` on macOS would remove it.

Comment: The absolute path didn't work for me. It would work for the install, but then the transpiling would fail because somehow it was looking for a relative path but the yarn.lock had the absolute path.

Comment: It seems with yarn `1.17.3` the `file:` prefix is still necessary in the following situation: Let's say you have package `bar` which has a local dependency `./dependencies/xyz`. If another package `foo` is using package `bar`, it will try resolve `./dependencies/xyz` relative to `foo` directory instead of relative to `bar` directory. After changing the dependency to `file:./dependencies/xyz` the problem was resolved.

Comment: In case anyone else stubles into this: I was having issues with getting a local dependency in a `yarn workspace` project to install correctly on Github Actions CI. Adding an explicit `file:` to the path in the individual workspace `package.json` allowed CI to resolve the dependency correctly.

Comment: Works like a charm `yarn add file:abspath`

Comment: It's worth noting that the package to be added necessarily needs to have a `version` field defined. Otherwise it fails with `Can't add "my-package": invalid package version ""`

Comment: How can you add a specific branch?

Comment: How to do this with yarn berry? (v2 and v3)

Comment: for me, it is always absolute path from the project root, not your current path when you run yarn.

Comment: For the `NPM` case, I use `npm add file:./../your-project`. It seems to be working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72520455/3874231

Answer (score 41):

### For yarn version >= 2.x (Yarn Berry)

To reference local packages, Yarn supports different [protocols](https://yarnpkg.com/protocols):

- `file:` creates a *copy* of the specified directory. This means that if you make a change to the local package, you need to run `yarn install` again to copy its new version. When specifying relative paths (starting with `./` or `../`) or absolute paths (starting with `/`), the `file:` prefix can also be omitted.
- `portal:` creates a *symbolic link* to the specified directory and resolves its transitive dependencies.
- `link:` creates a *symbolic link* to the specified directory but does not resolve its transitive dependencies. Confusingly, this is equivalent to NPM’s `file:` protocol.

To add a dependency, run `yarn add your-project@file:../your-project`.

Attempting to run `yarn add file:../your-project` (without the `your-project@` prefix) will result in the following error: `Usage Error: The file:../your-project string didn't match the required format (package-name@range). Did you perhaps forget to explicitly reference the package name?`.

An important difference between the different protocols is the way they resolve dependencies. Let’s say you have a package `a` that depends on a local package `b`. In `link:` mode, you have to run `yarn install` inside the `b`, while in `portal:` and `file:` mode, `yarn install` in `a` will install `b`’s dependencies like it would for any other dependency. If both packages depend on library `mylib`, in `link:` mode the library will be duplicated as `a/node_modules/mylib` and `b/node_modules/mylib`, which can cause problems with some libraries (because caches may be duplicated and the `instanceof` operator won’t work as expected because the constructors are duplicated). Because of this, I would always recommend using `portal:` for local dependencies and clear the `node_modules` folder of the `b` dependency.

Comment: can you explain why yarn behaves different than npm on `file:`? npm does the job right by linking instead of copying. Yarn just copies having you to delete the local dep from `node_modules` and having yarn ran again.

Comment: @Sebastian I don’t know why this decision was made, but as far as I understand, NPM only supports one way of referencing local packages (`file:`, which is equivalent to Yarn’s `link:`), while Yarn supports 3. I will update my answer to provide some more details about the differences between the 3 approaches.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to simply link to the local package (so changes in the local package are picked up without reinstalling):

```
yarn add link:./../your-project
```

See more on [yarn docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/#toc-adding-dependencies)

Comment: I had troubles using file: within docker and google cloud so this was the answer thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I tried the `file:` solution with yarn and never got it to work.  I chose a different route of including the package directly.  I was able to add a `watch` to     automatically rebuild and update the browser on file change.

**My Situation**

I had a git repository with two directories: [example/](https://github.com/bonafideduck/react-highlight-within-textarea/tree/101d1ef5dd78840fb0ed45ce7cc1597759cbe422/example) and [react-highlight-within-testarea/](https://github.com/bonafideduck/react-highlight-within-textarea/blob/101d1ef5dd78840fb0ed45ce7cc1597759cbe422/react-highlight-within-textarea) (I'll simplify to `mylib/` below).  The *example/* was a react application with a dependency in the *example/package.json* of: `"mylib": "file:../mylib/"` (a) and an inclusion in *example/src/App.js* of `import { MyLib }  from 'mylib'`.

**My Solution**

1. Remove *mylib* from the *example/package.json*.

   `yarn remove mylib`
2. Make the distribution part of my project.

   `(cd example/src && ln -s ../../mylib/dist mylib)`
3. Change the inclusion in *example/src/App.js*.

   `import { MyLib } from './mylib'`
4. Install watch in *mylib*.

   `(cd mylib ; yarn add watch)`
5. Add a watch command in `scripts` of *mylib/package.json* (b).

   `"watch": "watch 'yarn build' src",`
6. I now run this in a terminal (c).

   ```
   (cd mylib && yarn install && yarn watch &)
   (cd example && yarn install && yarn start)
   ```

**Success**

Now any time I make a change and save it in *mylib/src/* or *example/src/*, it gets rebuilt and pushed to the React page in my browser.

---

**Footnotes**

(a) These before settings are one of many attempts to use package.json to make this work.

(b) There probably are more correct ways of doing this, but it worked for me.

(c) I probably could have made this into a yarn script too.

Comment: which version of yarn you're running? This solution is for v.1 (I'll update answer with this info)

Comment: My yarn version is 1.22.10.  The code is https://github.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea .  Currently my workaround is succeeding, but isn't very snappy in reaction time, but I'm too busy fighting CSS and DOM to try changing to a **proper** solution.