# How to overwrite incorrect TypeScript type definition installed via @types/package

Tags: typescript

Say that I want to use `dotenv` module in my TypeScript project and install its .d.ts using `npm install @types/dotenv --save`. Then I realize that the types are not correct. For example, the `config()` function doesn't return boolean but a richer object.

How do I deal with this situation? Should I just copy the downloaded type definition to another file, update it manually and uninstall @types/dotenv? Is there a better way? (I need the fix right away, not after it has been merged by upstream maintainers.)

Comment: You can just add a new interface with the same name as the declaration and add the new method as contract.

Comment: It's the same method, just with the corrected signature.

Comment: That is why i tell you to create a new interface (wich use the same name as the interface in the d.ts) and add new method to it with the new signature (just like an overload).

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: The problem with the overload is that it won't correct the mistake, it will just give the correct implementation as an option. That definitely is a fix, but you will need to submit your alteration for the full fix. Either what you suggested, or this answer, is a good interim solution.

Comment: I have a similar problem but the problem in my .d.ts is with an interface that describes a data record. I tried redefining the interface correctly in my source file but it doesn't remove the error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would check that the version of `dotenv` and the version of `@types/dotenv` are aligned, that may be the cause of the function missing.

If they are, then the cleaner way would be to modify the .d.ts yourself.

In order to do this: `npm remove @types/dotenv`. Create a folder `types` on your project. Copy the whole **folder** `dotenv` found in `node_modules/@types` into it.

Then fix your d.ts in it and modify your `tsconfig.json` to tell it to also look in your new folder for missing types with `typeRoots` like this:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types",
        "./types/",
    ]
},
"files": ["./app.ts"]
}
```

(Don't forget to add `./node_modules/@types` or other types you got with npm that won't be found anymore.)

Hope it helps!

Comment: What if the types aren't missing? The repo I'm using is no longer maintained (jimp). The typings have errors but are declared in the jimp source directory (jimp.js and jimp.d.ts). I need my local replacement to override the provided types.

Comment: I found my answer. Thanks anyway! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627631/exclude-overwrite-npm-provided-typings

Comment: what if there's no `@types/` package, but instead the declaration is in the `module-package-name/index.d.ts` or `module-package-name/types/index.d.ts` ?

Comment: I think you need to have a folder where all your index.d.ts are stored within separate folders (with the name of your modules) and they *need to be named index.d.ts* so in your case you need to manually remove the "type" folder if it's present (if it's `module-package-name/types/index.d.ts`) I guess and include the folder containing module-package-name

Comment: What to do when they are not aligned?

Answer (score 93):

You can patch `@types/foo` locally for your app by  [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

1. Run `npm i -D patch-package`
2. Simply modify `node_modules/@types/foo` to suit your needs.
3. Run `npx patch-package @types/foo`. This creates a diff file in `patches/` that records the changes made from the last step.
4. Add `"scripts": {"postinstall": "patch-package"}` in `package.json`. This make patches to be applied each time people run `npm install`.

Comment: It makes me sad that this dependency adds 198 transitive dependencies to my project... also, warning to future users trying this solution.

Comment: If you don't want it to bloat your deps, just use npx to run it.

Comment: @MicahZoltu - Another solution is to use PNPM, which has this built-in and is a more fully-featured package manager anyway.

Answer (score 35):

A way that is not mentioned here is to put a type declaration in a `index.d.ts` file. For my case, the types from `@types/react-bootstrap` were not correct.

I wanted to use `bsClass` as declared in the documentation, but it did not exist in `Popover`. Instead they included a prop that does not exist on `Popover` namely `bsStyle`.

The fix for me was to remove `bsStyle` and add `bsClass`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Sizes } from "react-bootstrap";

// Overwrite bad declaration from @types/react-bootstrap
declare module "react-bootstrap" {
    namespace Popover {
        export interface PopoverProps extends React.HTMLProps<Popover> {
            // Optional
            arrowOffsetLeft?: number | string;
            arrowOffsetTop?: number | string;
            bsSize?: Sizes;
            bsClass?: string; // This is not included in types from @types/react-bootstrap
            placement?: string;
            positionLeft?: number | string;
            positionTop?: number | string;
        }
    }
    class Popover extends React.Component<Popover.PopoverProps> { }
}
```

## Update

I finally bit the bullet and [uploaded a PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/32199) to DefinitelyTyped for adding a few missing bsClass / bsSize declarations.

## Update 2: An example using declaration merging

I wanted the img `loading="lazy"` attribute for the `<img>` tag in React, but it's not merged yet. I solved it this way:

File: `global.d.ts`

```
// Unused import - only used to make this file a module (otherwise declare global won't work)
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused
import React from "react";

// Extend HTMLImageElement to support image lazy loading
// https://addyosmani.com/blog/lazy-loading/
declare global {
    namespace React {
        interface ImgHTMLAttributes<T> {
            loading?: "lazy" | "eager" | "auto";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only helps when types are *missing*. Sadly it doesn't help when they are wrong.

Comment: on a side node: you can also use `export {}` to make the file a module, instead of importing an unused one

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is this supposed to "remove bsStyle"? Doesn't it just merge declaractions?

Comment: There are 2 `declare module "react-bootstrap"` defined now - does this working  depend on the order TS processes them under the hood?  Is there a guarantee that your override will always be applied last?

Answer (score 33):

I would copy the declaration files from DefinitelyTyped, modify them locally, send a PR to DefinitelyTyped, and then follow the advice given on the following question to use the changes immediately: [How can I write and use custom declaration files that don't exist on DefinitelyTyped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796039/how-can-i-write-and-use-custom-declaration-files-that-dont-exist-on-definitelyt)

## Sending updates to DefinitelyTyped

1. Head over to the DefinitelyTyped repo: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/
2. Clone your fork locally. (often just `git clone https://github.com/YourUserName/DefinitelyTyped/`)
3. Create a branch for your updates (e.g. `git branch changes-to-xyz`)
4. Make changes to the package you're interested in.
5. Add and commit files. (`git add types; git commit`)
6. Then push them to your fork of DefinitelyTyped (`git push -u origin changes-to-xyz`)

## Using those updates locally

1. Create a `local-types` folder in your project.
2. Copy the DefinitelyTyped folder (let's call it `xyz`) you modified and into `local-types/xyz`.
3. From `local-types/xyz`, run `npm init --scope types --yes`.
4. From the root of your project, run `npm install local-types/xyz`

That's it!

Comment: For `yarn`, change the local step #4 to `yarn add file:local-types/xyz`

Comment: To work correctly, after package generation, I had to manually add the `@types/` scope in front of the package. Also, it's a good suggesting to fit the local package version with the ones of the package.

Comment: For newer versions of yarn (since v0.21.0 - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102686/how-to-install-package-with-local-path-by-yarn-it-couldnt-find-package), the `file` prefix is no longer supported

Comment: This would be the way to go if you are adding a type for something that is getting added to HTML that definitelytyped does not have yet, such as the aforementioned lazy loading attribute. But it is not the way to go if you need to add in something that has been deprecated - such as a width attribute on a table for HTML email generation.

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to override a function definition from the package fabric.js, in where a function `loadImage` now is being updated to return a Promise instead of taking a callback as second argument, after quite some trial and error, I found a way to override the original types by simply importing a file like this:

```
import { fabric } from "fabric"

declare module "fabric" {
  namespace fabric {
    //@ts-ignore
    interface IUtil extends fabric.IUtil {
      loadImage(url: string): Promise<HTMLImageElement>
    }
  }
}
```

surprisingly, this combination of an interface extending itself (and a @ts-ignore for typescript to ignore the fact that an interface shouldn't recursively define itself), works