# TS2430 (TS) Interface 'InAppBrowser' incorrectly extends interface 'Window'

Tags: cordova, typescript

I created a brand new Cordova TS project in VS 2015 and im getting

```
Error   TS2430  (TS) Interface 'InAppBrowser' incorrectly extends interface 'Window'.
  Types of property 'addEventListener' are incompatible.
    Type '{ (type: "loadstart", callback: (event: InAppBrowserEvent) => void): void; (type: "loadstop", cal...' is not assignable to type '{ <K extends "loadstart" | "abort" | "beforeunload" | "blur" | "canplay" | "canplaythrough" | "ch...'.
      Types of parameters 'type' and 'type' are incompatible.
        Type '"batterystatus"' is not assignable to type '"loadstart"'.
```

when I try to build it.

Then I thought maybe its because the template in VS2015 is too old so I downloaded VS 2017 and created another blank app. It builds fine on TS v2.3 but after I upgraded TS to v2.8 it breaks again.

I tried all the `.d.ts` definition I can find in github (DefinitelyTyped and Apache repo). None of them worked.

Is there a way to get it to work with TS v2.8 or am I stuck with v2.3?

Comment: If everything else fails you could override the definition files on your own as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40322788/5730444)...

Comment: Have you managed to find proper ts for InAppBrowser yet?

Comment: @SergTomcat nope. we ended up not using cordova in the end.