# React useCallback in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Type error: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any[]) any

Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any[]): any'.

```
 const handleImageSearch = useCallback(
 debounce((value) => searchUnsplashImage(value), 400),
   ^
  [],
 );
```

I have tried adding the

```
interface IFunction {
  (...argArray: any[]): any;
}
const handleImageSearch = useCallback<IFunction>(
 debounce((value) => searchUnsplashImage(value), 400),
   ^
  [],
 );
```

Befor adding props
[image]

But it does not work. Please help me with this.

Comment: what's the return type of `searchUnsplashImage`?

Comment: @codemax It returns nothing. It just updates the internal state with a set of images.

Comment: Where is the debounce function coming from and what is its signature?

Comment: @EamonnBoyle debounce has been imported from lodash.

Comment: Seems to be working for me here: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-jang-4jr5w?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @Yuval probably because `Cannot find module 'lodash' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: This issue only appears while building the app.

Comment: Seems to work for me also. Have you added both 'lodash' and '@types/lodash' packages and is the import statement correct?

Comment: @EamonnBoyle Yes, I have added both with correct imports

Answer (score 1):

oneI have been facing this issue on `.jsx` files, and I assume this happens only for `tsc` compilations for non `tsx?` files (not sure, though). Also, the weird point is, this is not getting detected by VSCode as an error.

Anyways, the issue is quite clear, it happens because `lodash/debounce` returns a `DebouncedFunc`, as can be seen in the below signature:

```
debounce<T extends (...args: any) => any>(func: T, wait?: number, options?: DebounceSettings): DebouncedFunc<T>;
```

To get around this you can try one of the followings:

- Disable ts check for that debounce call, i.e. add the following comment above `debounce()` function call

```js
useCallback(
 // @ts-ignore
 debounce(),
 []
);
```

- Better way, instead of ignoring ts-checks completely is to, separate the function into a different instance:

```js
const debounceFn = debounce(...);
const callback = useCallback((...args) => debounceFn(...args), []);
```

- Or even more concise:

```js
const callback = useCallback((...args) =>
  debounce((param1, paramN) => {
    /** Your Function Body */
  })(...args)
, []);
```

Obviously, this is a workaround, and adds more code. For me `// @ts-ignore` seems like a better option.

A much better solution would be to override React Types itself for `useCallback`, details: [How to overwrite incorrect TypeScript type definition installed via @types/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322788/how-to-overwrite-incorrect-typescript-type-definition-installed-via-types-packa), but that's all a personal preference.

*I hope this fixes your issue.*