# TypeScript + Express + Passport.js - Property id does not exist on type User

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, passport-local

I'm new to TypeScript, I implemented user authentication using Passport.js in a small app I'm making just for practice.

**Problem**

I'm trying to tell Passport.js to save the user property `id` into the session for further authentication, but I just can't find a way to tell TypeScript that the property `id` of `user` actually exists.

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(undefined, user.id); // Property 'id' does not exists on type 'User' 
});
```

The parameter `user` shows off as type `Express.User`, but it actually is an instance of a TypeOrm entity `User`. Searching through posts I found out I can extend the type `Express.User` to add the property that I need to use:

```
  // src/custom-typings/index.d.ts
  namespace Express {
    interface User {
      id?: number;
    }
  }
```

Doing this removes the error warning when coding, but when I try to compile the code, the error shows up again, but in my VSCode terminal!.

```
src/core/passport.ts:38:24 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'.

38   done(undefined, user.id);
                          ~~

    at createTSError (C:\Users\fvg\Desktop\Proyectos\passport-local-example\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:513:12)
    at reportTSError (C:\Users\fvg\Desktop\Proyectos\passport-local-example\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:517:19)
    at getOutput (C:\Users\fvg\Desktop\Proyectos\passport-local-example\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:752:36)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\fvg\Desktop\Proyectos\passport-local-example\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:968:32)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\fvg\Desktop\Proyectos\passport-local-example\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1056:42)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\fvg\Desktop\Proyectos\passport-local-example\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1059:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
```

I did add my custom typings into my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                       
    "module": "commonjs",                   
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "outDir": "dist",                   
    "rootDir": "src",                         
    "strict": true,                  
    "typeRoots": ["./src/custom-typings", "./node_modules/@types"],                     
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,     
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,       
    "resolveJsonModule": true,        
    "skipLibCheck": true,              
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

This is my project structure:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── core
│   │     └── passport.ts
│   │  
│   │
│   ├── custom-typings
│   │             └── index.d.ts
│   │
│   └── other stuff
│ 
│
├── tsconfig.json
```

All other solutions say that this is to way to fix this typical problem, but I just can't make it work, what am I missing?.

Comment: I had the same issue. I ended up following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54840439/15293927.

Answer (score 0):

Use your User class defined in the model instead which should have id. You could also replace id with any other unique identifier in your user type.

```js
passport.serializeUser((user: User, done) => {
  done(undefined, user.id); 
});
```

Comment: there's an error: `No overload matches this call` in this case

Answer (score 0):

Pass any "type" to the user attribute

```
passport.serializeUser((user:any, done)=>{
    done(null, user.id)
})
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score -2):

- Install the `@types/passport` using

  ```
  npm install --save @types/passport
  ```
- After that open the `index.d.ts` file, inside the declare global function there is an interface User object. just add whatever variable you want inside it e.g

  ```
  declare global {
   namespace Express {
     // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
     interface AuthInfo {}
     // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
     interface User {
         *username:string;
         yourVariable: any;
         id:number; etc*
     }
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Rewriting the types of a package is hard to replicate between developers or in docker container without creating a private version of the package.