# "JSX element type 'Camera' does not have any construct or call signatures" when using svg files

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am using nextjs  and I am using svgr plugin in my nextjs config to be able to use svg files as Components, my nextjs config:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    return config;
  },
  images: {
    disableStaticImages: true,
  },
};
```

and then I have all my svg files in a folder called icons in public/static so I can import icons like:

```
import {Camera} from 'public/static/icons'
```

but when I use `<Camera/>` I am getting the error:
JSX element type 'Camera' does not have any construct or call signatures.

It's a typescript problem but how can I solve this?
I tried creating a @types folder and adding index.d.ts
and added there:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your module type declaration as follows:

```ts
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React = require("react");
  export const ReactComponent: React.SFC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;

  const url: string;
  export default url;
}
```

`@svgr/webpack` transforms `svg` files into a module with default export with `string` type and `ReactComponent` property that can be used as a React component directly.

Then you may use it both ways:

```ts
import url, { ReactComponent as Camera } from './icons/Camera.svg'

const Component = () => (
  <>
    <img src={url} />
    {/* or */}
    <Camera />
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to next version 11.0.1 and removing the next-dev.d.ts fixed the problem because since this version if custom webpack config is detected next will not consider svg files as static files

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too. What I have found so far is that nextjs declares *.svg as StaticImageData:
`node_modules/next/types/global.d.ts:42`
If you will find how to redeclare the module type in the project, please let us know

UPDATE:
I patched nextjs this way:

```
\\ node_modules/next/types/global.d.ts:2
import * as React from 'react';

\\ node_modules/next/types/global.d.ts:43

declare module '*.svg' {
  export const ReactComponent: React.SFC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>
  const src: string

  export default src
}
```

Then I patched nextjs following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322788/how-to-overwrite-incorrect-typescript-type-definition-installed-via-types-packa#answer-54840439)

Comment: Upgrading to next 11.0.1 all I had to do was delete the next-env.d.ts and then it got fixed, because they fixed in this nextjs version ommiting static svg imports if custom webpack config is detected and now in the global.d.ts there is no type definition for "*.svg"