# New error when accessing properties of top "Object is possibly 'null'." after upgrading to TS 4.4.3

Tags: javascript, typescript

I recently upgraded my project to TypeScript 4.4.3 from 3.9.9.

My project's using `"strictNullChecks": true,` in its `tsconfig.json`, and runs in the browser, not server-side on Node.

In TypeScript 4.4.3, it seems like the type declarations for `top` has changed to `WindowProxy | null` (`node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`)

This means that I get the following error<sup>1</sup> wherever I try to access properties of `top`<sup>2</sup>: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=3&module=0#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBDMAHAqgJwDZwLwOQOgHcBLCAEzEPwzBAEMZjJ8ALNAUwDMBuOAej44AfHADyAIwBW7EPGJQ4SMFCjFxGAJ5wA5BACuGDNvzAgA)

```
const topUrl = top.window.location.href; // => Object is possibly 'null'.
```

**How can I ignore this category of errors only for when `top` is possibly null?**<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> I understand that this error is warning me against the scenario where my website is loaded in an iframe, and therefore can't access `top` due to XSS. This isn't an issue because my `'X-Frame-Options'` is set to `'sameorigin'` and will therefore refuse to load my website in a cross-origin iframe.

<sup>2</sup> I access properties of `top` because I use iframes inside my project a lot, where it loads sub-pages on the same domain.

<sup>3</sup> I could use the following fixes to get around this `Object is possibly 'null'.`, but I'd prefer not to, as my project is quite large and this fix would be tedious with minimal improvement.

```
let topUrl = top?.window.location.href || '';
```

```
let topUrl = '';
if (top) {
    topUrl = top.window.location.href;
}
```

I could also ignore these errors on every line with `// @ts-ignore`, but there's a lot of references to `top` and I don't want to clutter the project (also, other TypeScript errors on the same line would be ignored).

```
// @ts-ignore
const topUrl = top.window.location.href;
```

Comment: *and this fix would be tedious with minimal improvement.* Hrm, the code that you have there does sound like the right approach to me - a search-and-replace across files seems like it wouldn't be hard to accomplish. Is there something that makes it more tedious than that?

Comment: @CertainPerformance The project accesses many typed properties of classes on top, so the tedious part is setting `|| ''` or `|| 0` or `|| false` in each occurrence depending on how it's being used to not cause more errors. I just counted how many errors there are from this and it's around 1500, so I was looking for an easy way around to avoid/ignore this error 

Comment: The thing is, you are upgrading major versions. According to SemVer, switching major versions lead to breaking changes. So if your code is not compatible with the version you either have to upgrade your code or downgrade the version. Ignoring errors is always a bad idea, because they usually have a meaning. Use vanilla js instead of ts if you don't want type errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution which would possibly fit your needs. And there are 2 versions of the solution you can take into consideration.

Both of these versions work by overriding the built-in `lib-dom` with a npm package [`@types/web`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/web) which is also provided by Microsoft.

#### Beta but systematic one - Using the latest official ['lib override'](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/#lib-node-modules) from `typescript@4.5.0-beta`

Follow steps below and things are gonna work as you expect without any other code modifications:

1. Upgrade to `TypeScript` 4.5.0:

   ```
   npm i -D typescript@4.5.0-beta
   ```

   or install globally

   ```
   npm i -g typescript@4.5.0-beta
   ```
2. Install the `@types/web@0.0.1` type package which has `top: Window` type

   ```
   npm i -D @typescript/lib-dom@npm:@types/web@0.0.1
   ```

I have made some simple tests on this solution and managed to get behaviour you want.

The only shortcoming of this solution is that typescript@4.5 is still beta currently. But It worth your consideration since its final release will be just on next month.

[TypeScript 4.5 Iteration Plan](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45418)

#### Stable one - `typescript` 4.4.3 and switch the built-in dom lib.

1. install `@types/web`

   ```
   npm i -D @types/web@0.0.1
   ```

   notice that the install command is **different** from the above one.
2. Update your `tsconfig.json`. There are two cases to consider depending on if you have `lib` defined in your `tsconfig.json` or not.

   1. **Without "lib"** - You will need to add "lib": []. The value you want to add inside your lib should correlate to your "target". For example if you had "target": "es2017", then you would add "lib": ["es2017"]
   2. **With "lib"** - You should remove "dom".

The drawback of this second version of solution is, it cannot prevent your dependencies in `node_modules` from pulling in the TypeScript DOM library.

Please bear in mind that despite `@types/web` is up to version 0.0.40, only version 0.0.1 of `@types/web` has `top` typed `top: Window` instead of `top: WindowProxy | null` which is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I preface this answer with a strong warning that I would not do this to my project and encourage anyone in this position to fix the errors the proper way  using null coalescing or not null assertion. EG:

```
window.top!.scrollTo()
top!.scrollTo()
window.top?.scrollTo()
top?.scrollTo()
// etc..
```

Even though theres 1500 I think using some regular expression you could easily target a large portion of those errors and fix with ease. With that said heres some other options:

---

**I havent done this in a production project and might result in some other strange errors, its largely untested by myself outside of quick testing**

The summary of this solution is you could clone the lib.dom.ts file and make the modifications by hand.

1. Copy `./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts` to somewhere in your project, say `./lib.dom.modified-4.4.3.d.ts`
2. Make the modifications to remove the null type from `window.top` and `top` types

   ```
   // old
   // readonly top: WindowProxy | null;
   // new
   readonly top: WindowProxy;

   ...

   // old
   // declare var top: WindowProxy | null;
   // new
   declare var top: WindowProxy;
   ```
3. Update your `tsconfig.json` to remove `dom` as one of the libraries and add it to the list of types

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "ES6"
    ],
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES6",
    "types": [
      "./lib.dom.modified-4.4.3"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Now you have a custom dom library with the `top` property not nullable

---

Alternatively you could make a patch for lib-dom using git and apply it post install. Details about how to do that are outlined in several solutions of this question [How to overwrite incorrect TypeScript type definition installed via @types/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322788/how-to-overwrite-incorrect-typescript-type-definition-installed-via-types-packa#answer-54840439)

Answer (score 3):

### The problem

You decided to upgrade your compiler version, and, as mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69185885/new-error-when-accessing-properties-of-top-object-is-possibly-null-after-up#comment122780636_69185885), major software version changes almost always come with breaking API changes.

The correct way to solve your issue (prevent compiler errors) is to modify your source code to satisfy the compiler. You said that modifying your source code in this way would be a chore, and asked about modifying the compiler configuration instead such that you can avoid modifying your source code.

It is not possible to override the types in `lib.dom.d.ts` in new type declarations. TypeScript will emit additional errors if you attempt to do this, even if you disable type-checking of your new declaration file, resulting in an incompatible merging of your new declarations. Your only option is to exclude the built-in DOM library and provide your own modified version of it.

Here is an overview of how to do that:

### Starting TSConfig

You haven't provided your `tsconfig.json` file, so here's an example to use as a base, with the assumption that your source is organized in your repo's `src/` directory:

> Note: [`"strict": true` implies `"strictNullChecks": true`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)

```jsonc
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

### Creating the modified `lib.dom.d.ts` library

1. First download the `lib.dom.d.ts` file from the tag that matches your TypeScript version (4.4.3): https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.4.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts
2. Move the file to `src/types/lib.dom.d.ts` in your project
3. Remove the triple-slash reference on [line 18](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.4.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18) by deleting the entire line. (This will allow you to continue using other built-in libraries.)
4. Modify [line 17286](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.4.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L17286) from this:

   ```ts
   readonly top: WindowProxy | null;
   ```

   to this:

   ```ts
   readonly top: WindowProxy;
   ```
5. Modify [line 18350](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.4.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18350) from this:

   ```ts
   declare var top: WindowProxy | null;
   ```

   to this:

   ```ts
   declare var top: WindowProxy;
   ```
6. Save the file

### Modifying your TSConfig

Now that you have a replacement library for the DOM types in your program, you need to tell the compiler to use it that way. Here's what you need to change:

```jsonc
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom", // Delete this from the array
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    // ...
    // Add this array property
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ]
  },
  // ...
}
```

So the modified `tsconfig.json` now looks like this:

```jsonc
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

### Conclusion

That's it. Now you should be able to compile your program and reference `window.top` or just the global `top` as a non-nullable value without a compiler error.

You'll need to repeat this process every time you upgrade TypeScript. Is this strategy more sustainable than modifying your source code? That's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

instead that you shoud use `!`, that typescript ignores the fact that the value could be null which in your case it is not

```
const topUrl = top!.window.location.href;
```

if your ES-LINT complains on that you can set the in config file like that

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  rules: {
    ...
    '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off'
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: If I do that ESLint complains `ESLint: Forbidden non-null assertion.(@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion)`

Comment: I added also ES-LINT config, code how to turn off that, if it isn't necessary for you

Comment: Disabling the ESlint check would open a potential bug where a new or junior developer puts in a non-null assertion on some other variable that wasn't defined, and then cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize a [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) if you have not already done so. Then

- look at the place of your error
- see what you would need to replace it to
- use whatever tools you use to replace all occurrences of the source text to the target text
- if there are still errors, repeat

Once you have replaced all occurrences of issues this way, you will need to review your changes. You will find the changes via the VCS. If you use git, then the command is

```
git diff
```

See all the changes and whichever looks even a little bit suspect, investigate and see whether the automatic change was correct. If not, perform whatever you need to ensure that your code is correct.

Test everything. You would do well if you would create a separate versioning branch for this work which would be tested for a long time before it's being released to production.

Answer (score 2):

> I access properties of `top` because I use iframes inside my project a lot, where it loads sub-pages on the same domain.

`top` is potentially `null`...

> This isn't an issue because my 'X-Frame-Options' is set to 'sameorigin' and will therefore refuse to load my website in a cross-origin iframe.

But you're saying that's impossible, in which case...

```ts
function getTop(): NonNullable<typeof top> {
    if (!top) throw new Error('global var top is null');
    return top;
}
```

...then replace any occurrence of `top.example` with `getTop().example` so as to centralize all potential 'null' errors.

While this isn't the most simple solution, it should be the safest.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you state:

> I could use the following fixes to get around this Object is possibly 'null'., but I'd prefer not to, as my project is quite large and this fix would be tedious with minimal improvement.
>
> ```js
> let topUrl = top?.window.location.href || '';
> ```

I can appreciate the tedious nature of this task, but if you're insistent on using TypeScript, I must also be insistent that you employ this solution. It is necessary in TypeScript.

One way I would solve this problem would be to **use my code editor/IDE program to search/replace all text references in my project**. I use *Visual Studio Code* which allows me to Search and Replace specific text in my source files. It allows for Regex searching, including and excluding particular files. I'm certain that a great majority of code editors/IDEs have similar functionality.