# Is it possible to override a type identifier from `lib.dom`?

Tags: typescript

I'm using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) in my application so I have added [`@types/wicg-file-system-access`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/wicg-file-system-access) to make the api work with TypeScript. But in TypeScript 4.6 this api has been partially added to `lib.dom`, causing some of the types to clash. I have [started a PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/58389) to fix these issues, but there's one problem I'm not really sure how to fix. Specifically that both `lib.dom` and `@types/wicg-file-system-access` contain the following type:

```js
type FileSystemHandleKind = 'file' | 'directory';
```

And as a result I get the following error:

```
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FileSystemHandleKind'.
```

Normally I would just use a different name and move on, but in this case that would introduce a breaking change. Is there some sort of way to override or merge or perhaps 'undeclare' the type in `lib.dom`? Or am I forced to introduce a breaking change?

Comment: No, it's not possible to override types in `lib.dom.d.ts`, (but you can [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) with (extend) any `interface`s if the types that you're targeting are defined that way). For using a custom version of `lib.dom.d.ts`, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69539181/438273).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately a custom version of `lib.dom` is not really an option in the sense that I wish to contribute a fix to DefinitelyTyped. But it's good to know that it is impossible to merge types like this. That means I can start looking for other solutions.