# Adding a private javascript github package with a private dependency with yarn install

Tags: javascript, react-native, github, npm, yarnpkg

I'm currently trying to add two private packages with a SSH Key from github using yarn install. I wasn't able to get the 1st package to install with a .git ending, but was able to install it by removing the tag. Unfortunately, the 2nd package, which depends on the 1st is running into a problem when it tries to add the second package.

```
error Couldn't find package "...@git@github.com:.../...git" required by "...@git+https://github.com    
/.../...git" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this
command.
```

My package.json looks something like this -

```
"1st": "git+https://github.com/1st"
"2nd": "git+https://github.com/2nd.git"
```

Are there any workarounds to this problem? I'd like avoid editing the repositories directly if possible.

Comment: Please make sure, that the `package.json`of the 1st package includes the correct `"git+https://github.com/2nd.git"` path.

Comment: In the package.json, it has the correct path, but with a ".git" tag.

Comment: There is another Stack post with a helpful discussion for you [How to install package with local path by Yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40116358/13745258)