# How to install local package with Yarn v3?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, package.json, yarnpkg-v3

I bashed my head against the wall trying to install a local package using Yarn v3. Here all the things I tried:

1. Run `yarn add file:../hardhat-packager`
2. Run `yarn add ../hardhat-packager`
3. Manually add `"hardhat-packager": "file:../hardhat-packager"` in `package.json`
4. Manually add `"hardhat-packager": "../hardhat-packager"` in `package.json`

All of the above resulted in Yarn getting stuck at the installation step, as shown in the screenshot below. I waited more than five minutes and I made sure that my Internet connection is fast.

I know that there is an option to [link](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/link) a package, but that is not quite white I want. I don't want symlinks, I want the actual package files copied over.

How can I do this? I'm using Yarn v3.2.0

[image: Yarn Stuck]

Comment: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/ - yarn docs show multiple options for installing packages from different locations

Comment: @Ross those are the docs for Yarn classic (v1), my question is about Yarn v3.

Comment: True, it doesn't seem yarn add has changed in v3, though the docs don't specifically mention adding a local file.  It does appear the 'yarn init' docs may give you what you need - it creates/installs a package in a local directory - https://yarnpkg.com/cli/init

Comment: also `yarn add -h`, although not super helpful in this case :(

Answer (score 11):

To install local package for Yarn 3 you should use pattern packagename@location.

For an example:

```
yarn add hardhat-packager@file:../hardhat-packager
```

or if you have created a tarball with `yarn pack` it should look like:

```
yarn add hardhat-packager@file:../some_path/hardhat-packager-v0.1.0.tgz
```